# How to fill a listView in Android with data that they are saved on internal file (my_text_file.txt)

Tags: android, listview

I'm new in Android dev and I want to ask this.

I've create an Android program that saves passwords in a txt file.
I want to retrieve these passwords  and display them into a listView.

Below is the code that I wrote to save passwords to my file:

```
try {
        FileOutputStream fileout=openFileOutput("mytextfile.txt", MODE_APPEND);
        OutputStreamWriter outputWriter=new OutputStreamWriter(fileout);
        outputWriter.write(textView3.getText().toString()+"\n");
        outputWriter.close();

        //display password saved message
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Password saved successfully!",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Now this is my code that reads the file:

```
FileInputStream fileIn=openFileInput("mytextfile.txt");
        InputStreamReader InputRead= new InputStreamReader(fileIn);

        char[] inputBuffer= new char[READ_BLOCK_SIZE];
        String s="";
        int charRead;

        while ((charRead=InputRead.read(inputBuffer))>0) {

            String readstring=String.copyValueOf(inputBuffer,0,charRead);
            s +=readstring;
        }
        InputRead.close();
        textView4.setText(s);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I want to know if there is a way to display these passwords into a listView.

Namely I'm looking for the code. I appreciate any help.

> :NOTE: If that question is already answered, I'm sorry.

**SOLUTION**

Thanks to @mehd-azizi I finally found the solution to my problem.

change the read part to this :

```
public  String[] readFileAsString(String fileName) {
Context context = this;
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
String line;
BufferedReader in = null;
ArrayList<String> list=new ArrayList<String>();
try {
    in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(context.getFilesDir(), fileName)));
    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        list.add(line);
    }

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

} catch (IOException e) {

}
String[] stockArr = new String[list.size()];

return list.toArray(stockArr);
}
```

and use that like this to read the file and fill the ListView:

```
ListView listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,readFileAsString("mytextfile.txt"));
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the read part to this :

```
  public  String[] readFileAsString(String fileName) {
    Context context = this;
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    String line;
    BufferedReader in = null;
    ArrayList<String> list=new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(context.getFilesDir(), fileName)));
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            list.add(line);
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

    } catch (IOException e) {

    }
    String[] stockArr = new String[list.size()];

    return list.toArray(stockArr);
}
```

and use that like this to read the file and fill the `ListView`:

```
 ListView listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);

 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                    readFileAsString("mytextfile.txt"));

 listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```